# Multiple header in Drupal website

Tags: php, html, drupal

I want to make 2 headers one for home page and one for rest of website (they would be almost same just have little change). I'm using Drupal 7. Please guide me any simple way because I know bit difficult way through using its url.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Put each of headers in a separate block then position these 2 blocks in the header of your theme (menu structure then blocks).

For the one on the front page, go inside the settings of the block then check "Only the listed page" and add : `<front>`

For the one everywhere but on the front page, go inside the settings of the block then check "All pages except those listed" and add `<front>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. And I understand your answer. But the problem is I have already a block  "Main Menu" and I just want to duplicate it to make some little changes. But I didn't find how to make changes in this block "Main Menu" or duplicate this block.

Comment: If you just want to adapt the css (hiding parts of the menu or relooking it), just add css selectors based on the class front, this class is added to the body html element. Or not-front if you want to alter css on all pages but front one.

Comment: Else if you really need to alter the html structure, you will have to alter the view of this block with the hook : hook_block_view_main_menu_alter(...) : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7